# get json response from httpurlconnection

Tags: android, json, apache

I want to get Json response from httpurlconnection.
before I use httpclient and get httpresponse from this I get json.
but now I don't know how to get httpresponse from httpurlconnection.
I have tried to upload image by using this example:

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: use it. Its very simple and have more benifits.  http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: It's gradle :( I use Eclipse !!!

Comment: yes I am talking about eclipse. Please download jar file and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Yogendra but I'm not a pro in java can you convert this code to async http:

```
 public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath );

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath );
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               HttpResponse respons;

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 



               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


               StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
               builder.append(conn.getResponseCode())
                      .append(" ")
                      .append(conn.getResponseMessage())
                      .append("\n");

               Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
               for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
               {
                   if (entry.getKey() == null) 
                       continue;
                   builder.append( entry.getKey())
                          .append(": ");

                   List<String> headerValues = entry.getValue();
                   Iterator<String> it = headerValues.iterator();
                   if (it.hasNext()) {
                       builder.append(it.next());

                       while (it.hasNext()) {
                           builder.append(", ")
                                  .append(it.next());
                       }
                   }

                   builder.append("\n");
               }

               Log.i("Response", builder.toString());


               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = String.valueOf(conn.getContentEncoding());

              // Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                //     + conn.getHeaderField("server") + ": " + serverResponseCode);



               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/";

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class getServerDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String fileName;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile;
    String msg;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fileName = arg0[0];
        sourceFile = new File(arg0[0]);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath);

            msg = "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath;
        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        fileName);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                HttpResponse respons;

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append(conn.getResponseCode()).append(" ")
                        .append(conn.getResponseMessage()).append("\n");

                Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey() == null)
                        continue;
                    builder.append(entry.getKey()).append(": ");

                    List<String> headerValues = entry.getValue();
                    Iterator<String> it = headerValues.iterator();
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        builder.append(it.next());

                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            builder.append(", ").append(it.next());
                        }
                    }

                    builder.append("\n");
                }

                Log.i("Response", builder.toString());

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = String.valueOf(conn
                        .getContentEncoding());

                // Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                // + conn.getHeaderField("server") + ": " +
                // serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                            + " http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/";

                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
                msg = "MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.";

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(),
                        ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                msg = "Got Exception : see logcat ";

                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        } // End else block

        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        messageText.setText(result);
    }

}
```

call async class as

```
new getServerDataAsync().execute("source url");
```